# Querying YQL for external XML returning HTML

Tags: xml, cross-domain, yql

I'm querying an external URL with javascript using YQL. When I approach the XML-file normally I get the results as expected in my browser. When I query it using YQL (because we want to do a cross-domain ajax-call) I get weird HTML as response instead of the expected XML. This is my query:

`select * from html where url="http://locateandselect.kiala.com/kplist?dspid=DEMO_DSP&country=NL&language=&preparationdelay=&zip=3573&sort-method=&max-result=&zipfilter=" and xpath="*"`

Any thoughts what's wrong with my query here? I want to return the XML as you would get when you paste the URL in the browser so I can further process it with jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `html` YQL table to get XML data. You should use `xml` table instead. Try the following query

> select * from xml where url="http://locateandselect.kiala.com/kplist?dspid=DEMO_DSP&country=NL&language=&preparationdelay=&zip=3573&sort-method=&max-result=&zipfilter="

That returns XML.

**EDIT**
Rest call for the above query:[tinyurl.com/klnt29w](http://tinyurl.com/klnt29w)